# Error: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, charts, components

I want to graph the data I get from Ble on React-native in real time.

But I am getting this error;

Please help me...

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Note : If I don't add the isLoading part, I get this error,

> Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by:RNSVGPath InvalidNumber

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import hr from '../components/CharacteristicCard';
import ScreenContainer from '../components/ScreenContainer';
import Chart from '../components/Chart';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Math.floor((Dimensions.get('window').height - 150) / 3);

let counter = 0;
const slotsPerWidth = 100;
const initialState = {
  flow: [hr],
  isLoading: true,
};

class ChartScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    chartData: { ...initialState },
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(state) {
    counter++;
    return {
      chartData: {
        flow: [hr],

      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { flow } = this.state.chartData;

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <ScreenContainer>
          <View style={styles.main}>
            <View>
              <ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>
            </View>
            <Chart
              key="flow"
              data={flow}
              maxValue={1900}
              minValue={1750}
              slotsPerWidth={slotsPerWidth}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              marginBottom={20}
              lineColor="rgba(95, 92, 1, 1)"
              lineThickness={2}
              chartBackground="#17204d"
              horizontalGridLinesCount={5}
              gridColor="rgba(65, 95, 93, .4)"
              gridThickness={1}
              unit="ml"
              axisTooClose={10}
              labelsColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"
              labelsFontSize={12}
              marginLeft={60}
              labelsMarginLeft={15}
            />

          </View>
        </ScreenContainer>
      );
    }
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default ChartScreen;
```

Note (edit): This is my screen,

```
const DeviceScreen = ({
  route,
  navigation,
}: StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Device'>) => {
  // get the device object which was given through navigation params
  const { device } = route.params;
 
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [services, setServices] = useState<Service[]>([]);
 
  // handle the device disconnection
  const disconnectDevice = useCallback(async () => {
    navigation.goBack();
    const isDeviceConnected = await device.isConnected();
    if (isDeviceConnected) {
      await device.cancelConnection();
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
  }, [device, navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDeviceInformations = async () => {
      // connect to the device
      const connectedDevice = await device.connect();
      
      setIsConnected(true);

   
      // discover all device services and characteristics
      const allServicesAndCharacteristics = await connectedDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
      // get the services only
      const discoveredServices = await allServicesAndCharacteristics.services();
    

      setServices(discoveredServices);
  
     
       PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Permission Localisation Bluetooth',
          message: 'Requirement for Bluetooth',
          buttonNeutral: 'Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
          
        }
      );     
      };  
    getDeviceInformations();

    device.onDisconnected(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    });

    // give a callback to the useEffect to disconnect the device when we will leave the device screen
    return () => {
      disconnectDevice();
    };

    
  }, [device, disconnectDevice, navigation]);
   


  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={disconnectDevice}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily:"SairaExtraCondensedThin",textAlign:"center",fontSize:15,color:"white"}}>Antrenmanı Sonlandır</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.header} >
          <Text>{`Name : ${device.name}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Is connected : ${isConnected}`}</Text>
        </View>
        {services &&
          services.map((service) => <ServiceCard service={service} />)}
      </View>
       <View>

        <ChartScreen chartdata />
       </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well, you're not returning anything if `this.state.isLoading` is false.

Comment: I'm changing state with 'false' but I take same error

Comment: In `getDerivedStateFromProps` you're resetting the state without the `isLoading` prop. When the component renders again its `undefined` which is why the condition probably doesn't work. And `counter` doesn't do anything. I'm not sure what that does tbh.

Comment: How can I fix this? My goal is create a real time graph. and my data is `hr`.

Comment: I can't see graph in my screen. What is the problem? What do you think about this situation? I am editing my post. I add screen code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally return the loading state or loaded state with a simple ternary operator.

```js
return this.state.isLoading
  ? <ScreenContainer>
    ...
  </ScreenContainer>
  : <LoadedStateComponents /> // or this can be null or whatever you'd like
```

You can also keep the view the same, but when the component is loading the state, pass an empty dataset to the chart element's `data` property (or whatever will present an empty chart and prevent you from changing the DOM tree).

```js
return (
  <ScreenContainer>
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
      <Chart
        key="flow"
        data={this.state.isLoading ? [] : flow} // pass empty data object when flow is loading
        ...
      />
    </View>
  </ScreenContainer>
);
```

Comment: What is the LoadedStateComponents?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not getting error bu I can't see graph in my screen

Comment: What do you think about this?

Comment: LoadedStateComponent is just an example of another component that you would like to load when the `isLoading` value is false. You have to render something when `isLoading` is true, and something when it is false. I'll edit my answer with another simple idea you could try instead

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution looks like, you're going to want to add an else statement to your return statement with JSX.

```
function render() {
    const { flow} = this.state.chartData;

    if(this.state.isLoading){
        return(

        <ScreenContainer>

            <View style={styles.main}>
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>
            </View>   
            <Chart
                key="flow"
                data={flow}
                maxValue={1900}
                minValue={1750}
                slotsPerWidth={slotsPerWidth}
                width={width}
                height={height}
                marginBottom={20}
                lineColor="rgba(95, 92, 1, 1)"
                lineThickness={2}
                chartBackground="#17204d"
                horizontalGridLinesCount={5}
                gridColor="rgba(65, 95, 93, .4)"
                gridThickness={1}
                unit="ml"
                axisTooClose={10}
                labelsColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"
                labelsFontSize={12}
                marginLeft={60}
                labelsMarginLeft={15}
            />
            
            
            </View>
        </ScreenContainer>
        );
    } else {
        // This can also be a <LoadingSpinner /> or likewise component
        return null
    }
}
```

The problem is that you CAN'T return nothing, so when it loads and the answer is false, you return nothing and the program halts.

Comment: I can't add 'function' in front of render. I am getting error.

Comment: Sorry, don't add the `function` syntax and then try it, should work.